# Is my logic and reasoning correct? or at least on the right path?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Heres the question: 
Suppose that a player draws a card at random from a pack of cards, and wins $15 if an ace, king, queen, or jack is obtained, and otherwise wins the face value of the card on dollars. What is the expected amount won by the player?

So far I think since its 15 dollars per face car the max amount of money they can win is 240 dollars since there are 16 total face cards so $15 x 16 = 240$ So this would be the highest outcome. Then for the probabilities I'm assuming it would be 1/52 chance for 15$ and so one until 240 dollars?

Comment: "Path" unclear. What is your method?

Answer (score 1):

You compute the expected value as a [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).

The probability of winning $15$ is $4/13$, with the Ace and the three face cards. (We can assume a $13$ card deck - just one suit - and get the same answer.)

The probability of winning $2, 3, \ldots , 9, 10$ dollars is $1/13$ for each. So the expected amount is
$$
\frac{  4 \times 15 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + 9 + 10}{13}.
$$

You can finish the arithmetic.

Comment: So 2 - 9 is 1/13 probability, what about 10 - 14? or are those irrelevant?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the $10$. Numbers $1$, $11$, $12$ and $13$ correspond to the ace and the face cards.

Comment: Okay thank you that's what I thought, and that means 1 , 11, 12, 13 = 1/4?

Comment: No. Each of those cards has probability $1/13$, so $4/13$ total probability for $\$15$. There's no $1/4$ anywhere.

Comment: So that's why you multiplied 4 into 15 correct that makes sense, but when I calculate it, I don't get the right answer of 2.67

Comment: Why do you think $\$2.67$ is the right answer? It can't be since it's way too low. Only the $2$ card pays less.

Comment: Simulation of a million draws gives avg winnings $8.77 same as this Answer. (+1)

Comment: Wow turns out I was looking at the wrong answer guys thank you for the help though! now I see where I went wrong